# Custom Permission access check is always returning True in Managed Package

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, managed-package, permission-sets, custom-permission

I have created a custom permission and included it as part of 2GP package, after installing my package to the scratch org, customPermission always return true

```
import hasAppPermission from "@salesforce/customPermission/CustomPermissionName";
get hasAppAccess() {
    console.log("hasAppPermission", hasAppPermission);
    return hasAppPermission || false;
}
```

hasAppPermission always return true, even if it's not assigned to the user.

even In apex it returns true `System.debug(FeatureManagement.checkPermission('CustomPermissionName'));`

This works fine when I deploy my code using sf project deploy start instead of installing it as a package

Comment: I bet you are selecting "Install for All Users" when installing the package. This, unfortunately, adds all custom permissions in the package to all profiles (along with read access for all objects and fields from the package). You should ensure the package is installed using "Install for Admins Only", in which case only the System Administration profile will be updated to add the custom permissions...

Comment: No, I have installed using the sf package install cli, there is no such option to install for all or specific users. And I see the permission being enabled by default after installation, how can I make it to not assign this permission to any user upon installation

Comment: API-based installs like using the CLI default to Install for All Users.

Comment: Which is a disaster... this option needs to be killed, IMHO.

Comment: Did you manage to figure it out, I am getting the same issue, however mine is returning false instead, although the user has custom permission assigned through a permission set, not installed using for all user option.
I also tried creating a custom permission that is not part of the package and that does not work either - just working my way through API versions, my latest code was on 59, my exact same package although a 1GP package, works just fine.